Playwright tests behaving differently when ran in ado pipeline
To give some context, I have a function that interacts with a calendar on a web application.
Playwright will select a start date, and the web application will add an extra day to determine the end date. So an example, if playwright selects May 1st as the start date, the application will select May 2nd as the end date without playwright needing to do anything extra.
Afterwards I can hit a save button to proceed with the rest of the test.
When I run this outside of ADO everything behaves as expected after playwright selects a date on the calendar, the application changes the end date respectively.
When this exact same test is ran in our ADO pipeline, it fails and when I review the video of the failure I see that Playwright behaves as expected where it selects a start date but the web application wont change the end date, so the test fails because the web app didnt behave as expected.
Im curious if anyone can understand why the difference in behavior, this only happens when I run the tests in ADO the date validation tests all fail due to the web application not behaving correctly.
When I run playwright in ado/locally it navigates to the same URL.

Please share a [mcve]. Without code and a website to run on, plus pipeline details, it's going to be pretty hard for anyone to guess why the problem occurs.

I cannot provide any of that, as its proprietary, I suppose my question is, is ado known to cause these differences in behavior with web applications/automation software?

I'd try to recreate the problem from scratch without proprietary code. If it's a pipeline issue, then it should be reproducible minimally with a few lines of code and a couple config files. From the link above: "Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem."

The information provided in question does not allow for a further investigation of the issue. Since the issue is related to Azure Pipeline, can you share your pipeline definition and pipeline error log with us? What kind of Agent are you using?(Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent)
